# Automatic numbering of paragraphs applying to marginal notes, on both sides of one-column memoir class document

Tags: numbering, memoir, paragraphs

I am a novice user trying  to prevent the automatic numbering of paragraphs (using \countpar and \everypar) to also apply to side notes on both sides of a one-column memoir class document, using sidepar and marginpar for inner and outer margins respectively. I also tried to use marginnote but to no avail. Could some one please help ?

```
...
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,showtrims,final]{memoir}

% PACKAGES

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[final]{microtype} 

% PAGE LAYOUT
\setpagecc{247mm}{203mm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{200mm}{103mm}{*}
\setlrmargins{54mm}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{31mm}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{4mm}{32mm}{\onelineskip}
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

% PARAGRAPH FORMAT
\newcounter{ParagraphNumber}[chapter] 
\newcommand\countpar{\everypar{\stepcounter{ParagraphNumber} [\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{ParagraphNumber}]  }}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{\onelineskip}

% FOOTNOTE NUMBERING PER PAGE 
\usepackage{perpage} 
\MakePerPage{footnote} 

% THE DOCUMENT -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
%\countpar
1st paragraph.

2nd paragraph.

3rd paragraph
\marginparmargin{outer}
\marginpar{\begin{flushleft}Outer note\end{flushleft}}

4th paragraph
\sideparmargin{inner}
\sidepar{Inner note}

5th paragraph
\end{document}
```

...

Comment: Hello @YBI and welcome to the forum! Can you show us what you've tried so far by adding a MWE (Minimal Working Example) to your question?

Comment: Here is the source code. If I activate the \countpar command, then I goes awry.

Comment: I don't see any numbering, when `\countpar` is commented out. Is that already what you wanted to achieve? If not i must say that i haven't fully understood, what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: I would like the have the paragrahs numbered, but not the side notes please. When you remove the % before the \countpar then the numbering is activated.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the [marginnote package](https://ctan.kako-dev.de/macros/latex/contrib/marginnote/marginnote.pdf)?

Comment: I tried but it worked the same, as it seems that a margin note is viewed as a new paragraph, therefore as to be numbered, which is something I try to prevent.

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to achieve. If you want your regular (not `\paragraph`) paragraphs to be numbered then I think that you have to start each of them with a macro that inserts a number. Have you thought of using the `enumerate` environmemt which will number each `item` (a paragraph?) within it?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it but found out that within the enumerate environment, the  \marginparmargin{outer} command does not result in proper justification (right or left) depending on odd or even pages.

Comment: I also found that I could not control the placing of margin notes and side notes in the same paragraph... Could you please provide a working example spanning two pages with notes in the two sides of the same paragraph switching side when we change page ?